# why new Date('2015-07-01 01:00:00+00:00') works for chrome but not on safari?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, datetime, safari, momentjs

Chrome returns `Tue Jun 30 2015 18:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)`.

Safari returns invalid date for same function.

If ' ' is replaced by 'T' then it works but i don't know why.

`new Date('2015-07-01 01:00:00+00:00')`Does not work on safari

`new Date('2015-07-01T01:00:00+00:00')`Works on both browsers

Is there any specific reason?

Comment: What is with the `momentjs` tag? This is just a vanilla Date object.

Comment: new Date(moment('2015-07-01 01:00:00+00:00')) this works on safari and i want to know why?

Comment: Because Moment.js has a lot better date parsing and handling.

Comment: [`moment(String)`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/): "When creating a moment from a string, we first check if the string matches known ISO 8601 formats, we then check if the string matches the RFC 2822 Date time format before dropping to the fall back of new Date(string) if a known format is not found."

Comment: thanks guys for clarification ...

Answer (score 1):

The `T` is part of the ISO Date String format; if it's timezoned it should also have `Z` (or another timezone indicator) at the end.

The first example is not a standard timestring, but some browsers will attempt to parse it. I guess Safari does not.

For your edit - the `moment` works in safari because you are using the excellent Moment library to parse it, not the native Safari Date object.

My edit: See VLAZ's comment!

Comment: Minor correction - `T` is *optional* for ISO 8601 strings, however JS `Date` doesn't actually support all of ISO 8601 but a subset and there the `T` is not optional.